# How to map a 2D array in a 1D array in C++? (column-major)

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

Let W be the width of the 2D array, and H its height. with row-major layout, I can do this:

```
const int W = 3, H=2;
int m[H][W] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
int* oneD = &m[0][0];
assert(oneD[1*W + 2] == m[1][2]); // element 6, y=1, x=2
```

but how about column-major, any ideas?

Comment: Not sure that you can do this directly. Possibly you'll need to transpone the array.

Comment: @Alex: so first I have to transponse the array and then do a row-major layout?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure that it is the solution. You can also try to override `operator[]` to store in the transponed order.

Comment: What is it, C or C++? Your title has C++ you tagged with C.

Answer (score 2):

In C internally row major approach is used(m is laid out in memory contigously as 1,2,3,4,5,6) so that you could directly represent example  with oneD. However column-major layout cannot be represented so simple since C internally use row major approach. So, to get a correct column major approach one simply can use following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
const int W = 3, H=2;
int m[H][W] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
int* oneD = new int[H*W];
for(int i=0; i<W; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<H; j++)
        oneD[H*i+j]=m[j][i];
for(int i=0; i<H*W; i++)
    std::cout<<oneD[i]<<" ";
return 0;
}
```